# Cannot open access database after importing the backend database, originally connected over the network

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am just a beginner, as such, humbly request you to be as basic as possible.

below are the steps that I had taken while creating a split access database:

1. Originally created an access database in access 2013, which had a login form as default form on load, and it was mandatory to log in.
2. Split the database into back-end and front-end.
3. stored the back end database over the network in one of the computers (all systems are linked via LAN/wi-fi) and distributed the front end to different users.

This setup had worked fine so far. Users were able to operate the database perfectly fine. However, it was required that the database be imported back again (merge front-end and back-end). Below are the steps that I took.

1. Logged in as a superuser (there is a feature where I can bypass the login form by using shift+enter key, which then asks for superuser credentials. Once logged in, simply close the database and again open using shift+enter) and gained access to database design.
2. deleted the linked table, and imported the back-end database.

Now, when I connect my system to the network, and try opening the database, everything works fine. But if I disconnect from the network and try to open the database, IT JUST WON'T OPEN. Only the access software gets opened, and not the database.

What I fail to understand is why is my database still dependent on network when there clearly is no need for that?

Please help me understand where I am wrong, and also, how can I open the database without being connected to the said network.

Comment: Possibly, you still have linked hidden or system tables. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/View-and-manage-objects-by-using-the-Navigation-Pane-274dfc5a-281b-472b-94e2-ef931c5cc590#bm9) how to unhide them.

Comment: Upper case letters don't help anyone solve the problem. What does " IT JUST WON'T OPEN. " mean? Do you get an error message? Have you tried to reduce the problem to a minimal project? What have you tried?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Wow!!! It worked.. I had created a table and had hidden it and then split it. All I had to do was unhide it, right clicked on the table and clicked "Linked Table Manager" (just to confirm if it still is linked over the network, and it was!) and once confirmed, right clicked and selected "Convert to Local Table". Now, everything is working fine. Thanks a tonne.

Comment: @nicomp Apologies, it was only meant to exaggerate my frustration. I should have clarified it better. Anyway, issue has been resolved as of now. Thanks a tonne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As per [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat), I should repost my comment as an answer).

There were still linked hidden tables present. See [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/View-and-manage-objects-by-using-the-Navigation-Pane-274dfc5a-281b-472b-94e2-ef931c5cc590#bm9) how to unhide them.